# python 2.7 - Inserting input in cmd via subprocess, according to output

Tags: python-2.7, input, subprocess, stdin

I have this code for now

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args='test.bat'.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.stdin.write("n")
p.stdin.flush()
for line in p.stdout:
    print line
```

so when the batch file runs it asks

```
Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N]?
```

you type `n` and it pops again, next `n` closes it. but the stdin write only type the first `n` and not second. If i use it only with one `n` the code completes and finishes, but how do i give the subprocess 2 inputs?

Another Thing:

I would like to read the output as it goes so I can run something like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args='test.bat'.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in p.stdout:
     if line.startswith('Please type x/y"):
          p.stdin.write('x')
          p.stdin.flush()
     if line.startswith('please choose 1/2'):
          p.stdin.write('2')
          p.stdin.flush()
```

now the run won't enter the `for`, because the subprocess didn't complete.
The second thing, takes the 1st and complicates it. so an answer to the 2nd will suffice.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer hope it helps other people.

```
        p = sp.Popen(args='try.bat'.split(), cwd=WORKING_DIRECTORY, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        while True:
            nextline = p.stdout.readline()
            if nextline.startswith("enter x/y"):
                p.stdin.write("y")
                p.stdin.flush()
            if nextline == '' and p.poll() is not None:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(nextline)
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

It will be read line by line and act accordingly for every line you wish